# Python: Creating a dictionary from a file

Tags: python

I want to write a function that opens a file containing two lines, and creates a dictionary. The first line is the string giving the keys and the second line is the string giving the values.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How are the keys/values separated? Spacing? Comma?

Comment: What have you tried? And what's in your file?

Comment: I was not given a file, i'm just supposed to write an arbitrary function that does this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique is to use [*file.readline()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) to extract a line at a time.  Use [*str.split()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to break it into keys (whether you need an explicit delimiter or not depends on your data).  Once the *keys* and *values* are obtained, [*zip()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) them together and call [*dict()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#func-dict) to make the final dictionary:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    keys = f.readline().split()
    values = f.readline().split()
d = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

For example, given "somefile.txt" like this:

```
python ruby go c rust swift
snake gem verb letter oxide race
```

The resulting dict *d* will be:

```
{'python': 'snake', 'ruby': 'gem', 'go': 'verb', 'c': 'letter', 'rust': 'oxide', 'swift': 'race'}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short and simple

```
file = open("file.txt", "r").read()
lines = file.split("\n")
dictionary = dict()

while (i < len(lines[0])):
    dictionary[lines[0][i]] = lines[1][i]
```

Comment: Have you tested this code? I don't think it works. `i` is never initialized. `i` is never incremented so the program would probably never exit. The file handle is never closed. Stylistically, solutions that don't rely on positional indices like `[0]` and `[1]` are preferred because they are easier to read. `dictionary = {}` is preferred over `dictionary = dict()` for initializing an empty dictionary. The accepted answer is short and simple.